# Asterisk start dialpan many times at the same times

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, dialplan

Please help understand out what's going on.
Asterisk starts dialpan many times for one input call. 
I use  Asterisk 15.4.0 (FreePBX 14.0.5.25), 
My extensions_custom.conf:

```
[bpms_input]
exten => _[A-Za-z0-9]!,1,NoOp(>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = ${EXTEN} CONTEXT = ${CONTEXT} DATE = ${DATETIME} STATUS = ${DIALSTATUS})
same => n,Wait(10)
```

Asterisk log:

```
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000000", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000000", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000001", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000001", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000002", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000002", "10") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000003", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000003", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000004", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000004", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000005", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000005", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000006", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000006", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000007", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
  == Setting global variable 'SIPDOMAIN' to '192.168.2.11'
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000007", "10") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:1] NoOp("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000008", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Exten = MyTrunk CONTEXT = bpms_input DATE =  STATUS = ") in new stack
    -- Executing [MyTrunk@bpms_input:2] Wait("PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000008", "10") in new stack
```

**Edited:**

My provider answered to my request. 
He says "3 Invitations were created by the 3 available active registrations. Each of the invitations to the line". 
Screenshoot:
[image]

**Additional info:** 
On the old FreePBX(10.13.66-8) the problem not was repeated. But I need a fresh version of FreePBX

**Additional info 2:** 
I compare registration request from old and new FreePBX version.
New version additional include parameter "line" to request's contact. 
The parameter value is automatically generated each time. 
While I can not disable sending this parameter.
I create a trunk in the pjsip.registration_custom.conf file. 
But when specifying the parameter "line = no" asterisk full stops registration attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the section

```
[MyTrunk]
type = registration
```

I deleted the parameter

```
line = yes
```

Then the asterisk stopped seeing my trunk by

```
pjsip show registrations
```

I have removed the parameter from the same section.

```
endpoint = MyTrunk
```

Now all works.

PS: This changes impossible create from UI FrePBX. I have to disable trunk from UI. Then i recreate sections (`type=registration`, `type=identify`, `type=auth`, `type=endpoint`, `type=aor`) in `pjsip.registration_custom.conf`

PS2: Syntax

```
[MyTrunk] (+)
```

no work here.

Answer (score 1):

Acordinly to your log thoose calls are DIFFERENT(PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000008 is not same as PJSIP/MyTrunk-00000001)

Use tcpdump or sip debug to see packet.

Likly your provider have setup - if no valid response from server  - do recall.

P.S Try not use such providers. It is bad sign.

Comment: My provider answered to my request. He says "3 Invitations were created by the 3 available active registrations. Each of the invitations to the line". Could you tell, why Freepbx (asterisk) creates multiple registrations at the same time. Thank you. Provider's screenshoot attached to original question

Comment: asterisk -rx "sip show registry". If more then 1, search in your config files.

Comment: Command "pjsip show registrations" showed only 1 registred (i use pjsip trunk). But the call still opens many channels

Comment: On the old FreePBX(10.13.66-8) the problem not was repeated. But I need a fresh version of FreePBX

Comment: Play with re-register timeout etc. Or just put Progress/Answer as first line in your dialplan.

Comment: I compare registration request from old and new FreePBX version. New version additional include parameter "line" to request's contact. The parameter value is automatically generated each time. While I can not disable sending this parameter. I create a trunk in the pjsip.registration_custom.conf file. But when specifying the parameter "line = no" asterisk full stops registration attempts